# Best framework for HTML and JavaScript based hybrid mobile application development with cordova

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I am new to hybrid mobile application development and I want to develop a hybrid mobile application using HTML5 and Jquery.
I had read many article related to this but still have confusion that which framework will be the best open source framework for above development and is the cordova is also best for build an hybrid app.
Please suggest what will the best solution for complex and non-complex hybrid mobile application development.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go with HTML5 and jQuery, [jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/) is great framework

a specialized [theme options](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/) is also available for jQuery mobile.

there is also native like theme developed in top of jQuery mobile. [NativeDroid2](http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/material/), for more have a look at

http://www.gajotres.net/top-10-best-looking-free-jquery-mobile-themes/

**I'd advice you to not to stick with jQuery for mobile as it is dying and never meant to use for mobile apps.have a look at http://www.gajotres.net/why-jquery-mobile-is-not-relevant-any-more/**

For complex apps I'd advice you to use [angular](https://angularjs.org/) and [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) as it has MVW architecture.